# String compare in Struct (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, struct

I need search a large struct and find the index of all the components with the same name.

For example: If the name is 13hy I need an array [1,5] returned

```
 structure(1,1).name = '13hy'
 structure(2,1).name = '64hy'
 structure(3,1).name = '37hy'
 structure(4,1).name = '07hy'
 structure(5,1).name = '13hy'
```

I have tried:

```
 strcmp(structure.name,'13hy')
 ismember(structure.name,'13hy')
 strfind(structure.name,'13hy')
```

and I keep getting the error 'Too many input arguments.'
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to traverse the structure, using a [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)-based [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to test for the desired name:

```
find(arrayfun(@(n) strcmp(structure(n).name, '13hy'), 1:numel(structure)))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. What is the @(n) I have never seen that before.

Comment: It's used for defining an anonymous function. Check the link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use []: 
strcmp([structure.name],'13hy')

It chains the content and allows you to compre and use the struct very much like a usual variable.

Enjoy!